# how to find two's best answers

Tags: java

I am trying to find two's greatest numbers that are entered from the console.
I found the first one, but the solution for the second one is not working. The program is compiling and running. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingSecondHighestScore_4_09 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double max = 1;
        double score2 = 0;
        String firstName = "";
        String secondName = null;
        System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        while(x > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Sudent's name");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Student's score");
            double score = input.nextDouble();

            //find max
            if(score > max)
            {
                max = score;
                firstName = name;
            }

            //find second max
            if(max < score2  || score < score2)
            {
                max = score2;
                score = score2;
            }
            else if(max > score2  && score2 < score)
            {
                score2 = score;
                secondName = name;
            }


            x--;
        }
        System.out.println("The student: " + firstName + " has the greatest score: " + max);
        System.out.println("Second studemt " + secondName + " with second results: " + score2);

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should have the `homework` tag.

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger what do you see?

Comment: It's from the exercises of the book introduction to programming with java from liang, but it is not homework, I mean i am doing them by myself, they are not homework, I am doing them just as exercise

Comment: the variable for the secondScore is taking the value for the firstScore

Comment: In that case, now is a good time to learn to use the debugger. This won't be the last bug you ever have. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit more elaborate implementation (my waking up excercise of today):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TopScores {

    private static final int TOP_SELECTION_SIZE = 2;

    public static class Student {
        private final String name;
        private double score;

        public Student(String name) {
            if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be empty");
            }
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(String score) {
            try {
                this.score = Double.parseDouble(score);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal score: " + score);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s with score %s", name, score);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<TopScores.Student>();
        System.out.println("Please enter students. Press <RETURN> to stop.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean enteringData = true;
        while (enteringData) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter student's name: ");
                Student student = new Student(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Enter student's score: ");
                student.setScore(input.nextLine());
                for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
                    if (student.getScore() > students.get(i).getScore()) {
                        students.add(i, student);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (students.size() == 0) {
                    students.add(student);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                enteringData = false;
            }
        }

        int studentsToDisplay = Math.min(TOP_SELECTION_SIZE, students.size());
        if (studentsToDisplay > 0) {
            System.out.println("Top students:");
            for (int i = 0; i < studentsToDisplay; i++) {
                System.out.println("* " + students.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No students to display");
        }
    }
}
```

I created a separate class Student which holds name and score, validates the input and creates the display format for one student.

To determine the top scores I keep all the entered students sorted in a list by adding each new student in the correct position.

The user doesn't have to enter the number of students beforehand but can terminate data entry by entering an empty line (or an invalid score).

After data entry is finished the desired number of top scoring students is printed.

This approach is more flexible; printing the top 3 or top 10 students is a matter of changing the value of TOP_SELECTION_SIZE.

Most important takeaway: try to think in classes (in this case Student) where possible and delegate sensible responsibilities to each class.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I will just give you a few hints:

- When you find a new `max`, what should happen to `score2`?
- Should you look for a new `score2` even if you found a new `max`?

Answer (score 1):

If we want to address the if structures, consider rearranging to something like this:

```
if (/* new score beats second score, but not first */) {
    // replace second score
} else if (/* new score beats both first and second */) {
    // move first score down to second
    // assign a new first score
}
```

Let your thought process to correspond closely to the code, which will clarify what each block should do, thus localizing any logic errors.

Comment: I modified it like thisif(score > score2  && score < max)
   {
    score2 = score;
    secondName = name;
    
   }
   else if(score2 > max  && score2 > score)
   {
    score = score2;
    max = score2;
    
    secondName = name;
   }

Comment: First, make sure your condition for the new score beating the first and second score is correct: `score > max` should be enough and should work. Second, move and assign the score variables correctly: `score2 = max; max = score;`.  Think **very** hard about the boolean errors in your version of the code.

Comment: Third, reassign the names correctly: `secondName = firstName; firstName = name;`. Name your variables something that reminds you what they hold, this will be an invaluable skill throughout all of your programming. Also, practice stepping through and tracing your program using pencil and paper; my high school teacher forced me to do that to reduce logic errors. As an additional tip, add `println` statements in places (like after assignments) so you can see when values change and to what value they change.

Answer (score 1):

I think when score is greater than max then have to shift max into second score and set max with new score....
And
When the score is between max and score2 then have to update score2 only with new score

```
        //find max
        if(score > max)
        {
            score2 = max;
            max = score;
            secondName = firstName;
            firstName = name;
        }

        //find second max
        if(score < max && score > score2)
        {
            score2 = score;
            secondName = name;
        }
```